# Php long query execution

Tags: php

I run a procedure that takes about 20 minutes to complete, I just wonder if PHP can keep the connection active until the process finishes.

To be clear, this page will have a button which when you press it will call a php page to run a sql query, in the main page I just wait for the Http request to be complete to send a success message.

Comment: Why don't you try it. Shouldn't take more than 20 minutes ;)

Comment: Why is the background operation so heavy?

Comment: @byoigres You can set a new `max_execution_time` for any given script. But your first priority ought to be asking *why is this query taking so long*?

Comment: You should decouple the process from the HTTP request cycle. Expecting your user to reliably keep a browser open and connected for 20 minutes will always be a hack.

Comment: If you're running it from a web browser, then the web server will also have a timeout value, probably no more than 5 minutes... but a user waiting more than a few seconds for his browser to respond wil almost certainly get impatient

Comment: Do you implement the nested inner join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  queries that are set to take up some time, you should move some automation requests into the mix, preferably cronjobs if you have access to a linux server.

With cronjobs, you can create enteries in the database for specific values, linked to the user. The cronjob will kick in lets say, every 5 minutes to execute a query if a pending query has finished. This will minimize the fact the user will need to sit on the page until completion.  Because you should know, the second the user navigates away from the active page; all active connections, queries etc will stop.

Once the script has complete, make a custom message at the end to send to the user letting them know that their process has been completed.

You should also know, PHP works down the script, from line 1 to the end; so if your hang is on line 40 for example; the script will sit on that line until the query has completed then carry on processing.

**Edit: This is for example purposes only to point you in the direction that i'm getting at, and should not be used as you see it. This is merely a markup example**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['ButtonToExecute']))
    {
        // Query to update a table in your database which an external PHP script will work with
        // Example Table Structure:
        /*
            Username
            State

        */
        if ($state == 0)
        {
            // Then update state to 1 with username to the username for the query to take place on

        }
        else
        {
            // Warn user that their process will take longer to complete as their already is an active query in process
            // but add them to a secondry pipeline which will be picked up on the next cronjob interval
        }
    }
?>
```

On your cronjob, might have:

```
<?php

if ($state=='1')
{
    // Execute your script
    // After query execution update state to 2

    // if state == 2 then insert custom message/email to send
}

?>
```

Edit your crontab:

```
yourpreferrededitor /etc/crontab
```

^ Where yourpreferrededitor means your text editor, whether nano or other.

and your cronjob line:

```
* * * * *  root /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron.php
```

^ This is taken from a current cronjob I have constantly running set for every minute of every day

*A Cronjob will give the user the ability to navigate away from the page, because as I mentioned above, the second the user navigates away from the script.. All on going processes stop. The cronjob will carry on running throughout without no user interaction needed (apart from they make the initial request)*

Comment: Good point. But many clients want a way to trigger the job at the time they choose. So we often have to implement in a way which allows running the querry as cronjob OR on user request. Live would be easyer if they would just use the commandline ;)

Comment: The user request can be made by pressing the button, which then locks the next cronjob in their name; I'm working on a markup script. for example purposes only; and should be used as a reference not for production

Comment: @OliverA. Could you skim over my edit, and tell me if I should have a more in-depth example? Or get the jist (I understand you are not the OP, but other comments would be beneficial for the OP)

Comment: @DarylGill You could go a little more in-depth about the usage of cronjobs for this purpose; why have a seperate script to run the connections? Why should their be requests in the "pipeline", what is the main purpose of running a PHP script which is not accessible by the standard user and only the cronjob?

Comment: @user1902584 As the user provided no code of what they have tried, I have only given them an example of the usage and a rough outline on what they should do -- if they decide to take up the cronjob solution, I will not do the entire job for someone if their isn't anything they have provided for me to work with;

Comment: Your example seems clear to me but having a cronjob run every minute seems a bit strange to me. Id rather suggest starting a script if required or running a worker thread.

Comment: @OliverA. I just took this from mu active cronjobs on my server; and there needs to be a timeline which it will run the PHP script to check if there is any requests in the database for the query to execute, hence the structure for `state` -- further: `State = 0 // Nothing requests` -- `State = 1 //User Requested` -- `state = 2 // Process On-Going` -- `State = 3 //Process Complete and will be reset to 0` --- Something along those lines, it depends how the OP will handle if they go with a solution like this

Comment: @DarylGill I gues it depends on the tools you already have in use. Our product already has a build in crontab editor so it was easy to just take the command from the crontab and start it from code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in an ordinary php script if you set the timeout limit and ignore user abort but this is a bad idea because your user will have no feedback if the script worked.

At the company I work at we had the same problem
What we did:

1. Run the query in a separate script.
2. Start the script WITHOUT waiting for results
3. Split the query into multiple parts (using limit and offset)
4. Have the query script write messages to a temp file
5. Implement a status screen fetching the current state from the log via ajax

BTW an example for all the wise guys asking why it takes so long:

using a [transitive hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) can speed up your application a lot if you have to deal with a tree with millions of nodes but building it can take hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

You may want to take a look at [Set Time Limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP ini you can set a max-execution time for scripts, however you NEVER want to have a user sit on a page loading screen for that long.

One thing that I could suggest would to e increase your max execution time to something around 30 minutes, and then call this in javascript after a page has already been rendered, so the user will not be left in the dark not knowing what the script is doing.